# Express with Pug template: Inheritance, how do I make Block work using different routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

The Block inheritance doesn't seem to be working and Im not sure why not.  I have two pug files.  One, about dot pug and the other h2 dot pug.  H2 file should replace the default block content in the about file block content but nothing is happening.  My files are in the views folder setup on two different routes if that matters.  I'm new to Pug and can't figure it out.  Here is my repl:

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/ImpassionedWornAssembler)

**about.pug**

```
html 
  head

body 
  block content 
    h1 Hello #{name}
```

**h2.pug**

```
extends about.pug

block content
   h2 hello PPL
```

Answer (score 2):

The about.pug file, as @Absor said needs to be rendered.  The why is because the file with the extends keyword is the one that needs to be rendered.  I initially thought it was the other way around.  I searched many tutorials tying to understand this.

Example:

```
// Layout.pug  -- redundant html structure I want included throughout 
html 
     body
         h1 Hello World!
         hr
         block content

// About.pug  -- This is the file I will render. app.get('/', (req,res)=> {res.render('about')})

extends layout
block content
     h2 Hi my name is Ron!
```

Result:

## Hello World!

---

### Hi my name is Ron!

Answer (score 1):

You have to just render the template that you have the overrides in (h2.pug). For example if your root route is

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('h2');
});
```

you can see "hello PPL" when requesting the page. You can now also see that any additions that you make to about.pug are also visible.

Comment: Thanks for the try but that doesn't solve it.  I already have about.pug on the root route, if I put h2.pug on the root route also, only about.pug shows because it is the first declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  More of an explanation was needed however.  I finally found a tutorial explaining how it works.